# How to simplify this less css code?

Tags: string, variables, less, interpolation

I currently have this code :

```css
input[type=text] {
    background:transparent top center no-repeat;
    height:30px;
    font-size:13px;
    color:@greyBlue;
    padding:0 10px;
    border:none;
    &.long {
        background-image:url("/img/input_long.png");
        width:214px;
    }
    &.medium {
        background-image:url("/img/input_medium.png");
        width:96px;
    }
    &.short {
        background-image:url("/img/input_short.png");
        width:55px;
    }
}
```

Do you know if I can simplify that by just changing the filename part with a variable?
Something like this :

```css
input[type=text] {
    @input = "";
    background-image:url("/img/input_@{input}.png");

    &.long {
        @input = "long";
    }
}
```

If course this doesn't work, but if you have any idea about a functionnal way... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a mixin

```css
.bgImg(@input) {
     background-image:url("/img/input_@{input}.png");
}
```

and call it accordingly:

```css
&.long {
    .bgImg("long");
}
```